# Tpay payment notification not work in Cakephp

Tags: php, post, cakephp, payment

I'm having trouble accepting tpay payments.
The payment itself via the tpay website is successful. The money is credited to the account.
The problem occurs when, on my website, I want to capture payment information that tpay sends using the POST method (like CRC info).

My website is based on CakePHP 4.

To get the POST data, I use this:

```
$this->request->getData();
```

I noticed that the action in the controller doesn't even see that the request is POST.

This is the code I use.

```
public function payment()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    echo "TRUE";
    $query = $this->Payments->query();
    $query->insert(['name', 'crc', 'description', 'created'])
    ->values([
        'name' => 'TR-532',
        'crc' => $this->request->getData('tr_crc'),
        'description' =>  'My description',
        'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ])
    ->execute();

}
```

Any advice, or maybe someone has already encountered this issue ?

Comment: clear your logs, make new request, read log and post in your question.

Comment: @Salines I found this log that can be the problem https://jsfiddle.net/s9bc0zd3/

This is the AppController.php file: https://jsfiddle.net/bnxgwtqL/